# como insertar una nueva columna y filas a un excel alojado en el servidor?

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes comunidad pregunta lenguaje C#? 
estoy realizando unas modificaciones a un excel alojado en mi servidor necesito recorrerlo, revisar si las filas están vacías agregar una fila nueva con encabezado y llenar la fila nueva con la sumatoria de dos campos, e revisado muchos link paginas de como hacerlo y no e podido dar ala solución, se me encargo que usara la librería interop de office .
este es mi codigo:

```
protected void btnACS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //variables para poder manipular el excel 
    Excel.Application xlA;
    Excel._Workbook xlWB;
    Excel._Worksheet xlWS;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.Range Rng;


    //Inicializar el excel y obtener el objeto de la aplicacion 
    xlA = new Excel.Application();
    xlA.Visible = true;

    //abrir excel para manipular sus datos
    xlWB = xlA.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("." + 
    "/Carpetadondeestaelarchivo/nombreexcel.xlsx"), 1, true, 5, "", "", true, 
    Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "/t", false, false, 1, true, 1, 1);
    xlWS = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWB.Worksheets[1];

    // seleccionar rango activo
    Rng = xlWS.UsedRange;

    // leer las celdas
    int rows = Rng.Rows.Count;
    int cols = Rng.Columns.Count;

    //recorrer las celdas e introducir una fila nueva con una formula
    if (rows != null && cols != null)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++)
            {
                xlWS.Cells[1, 6]="Titulo";//Inserta titulo 
                xlWS.Cells[2, 6] = "=([@filaseleccionada]-[@filaseleccionada]+[@filaseleccionada])";//Inserta formula 
            }
        }
    }

    //Para guardar los cambios y cerrar todo en el archivo
    xlWB.Save();
    xlWB.Close(true,misValue,misValue);
    xlA.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWS);
    releaseObject(xlWB);
    releaseObject(xlA);
}
```

necesito combinar donde esta el for con la inyeccion de la formula soy nuevo en el mundo del c#

Comment: para que quede mas claro el código lo estoy ejecutando en la action onclick de un botón, boton el cliente solo lo oprimira y se actualizara el excel y luego lo dejara listo para descargar

Comment: Rodrigo, mira si te sirve esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16305098/4092887) o busca "si no lo has hecho aún" `c# excel range add row`. Saludos

Comment: buenas tardes mauricio ese es el código k agregue revisando tus consejos pero me alega por los insert los probé de al siguiente manera tambn Range.Insert(Object, Object), worksheet.Rows.Insert(dato al azar); worksheet.Rows["3"].Insert(); inlcuso lso misomos dentro del range y nada dice k el insert esta malo

Comment: este código ahora me arroja un error Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Comment: Usa `ctrl+k` `ctrl+d` para organizar el código. Mira esta [respuesta acerca de ese error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14364664/4092887).

Comment: cuando realizas el for noto que usas las variables rowIndex, colIndex, pero estas donde cambias su valor? porque no veo correcto que queden fijas, deberias ir cambiando en cada loop

Comment: A donde dejaste la respuesta? la pregunta debe ser respondida y explicada en la seccion respuestas, no en la misma pregunta, porque si no, no queda claro que paso con la misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto el problema en todo sentido,les dejo el código comentado por si a alguien le sirve, este botón actualiza un excel en un servidor, le agrega una fila con una formula y lo descarga, dándole al usuario la elección de donde guardarlo

```
protected void btnACS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //variables para poder manipular el excel 
    Excel.Application xlA;
    Excel._Workbook xlWB;
    Excel._Worksheet xlWS;
    Excel.Range Rng;


    //Inicializar el excel y obtener el objeto de la aplicacion 
    xlA = new Excel.Application();
    xlA.Visible = true;

    //abrir excel para manipular sus datos
    xlWB = xlA.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("." + 
    "/carpetaenelservidor/nombreexcel.xlsx"), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
    xlWS = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWB.Worksheets[1];

    // seleccionar rango activo
    Rng = xlWS.UsedRange;

    // leer las celdas
    int rows = Rng.Rows.Count;
    int cols = Rng.Columns.Count;

    //recorrer las celdas e introducir una fila nueva con una formula
    if (rows != null && cols != null)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++)
            {
                xlWS.Cells[1, 6] = "Tituloencabeceradelafila";
                xlWS.Cells[2, 6] = "=([@filaseleccionadaenexcel]+ 
                [@filaseleccionadaenexcel]*[@filaseleccionadaenexcel])";
            }
        }
    }

    //Para guardar los cambios y cerrar todo en el archivo
    xlWB.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    xlA.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWS);
    releaseObject(xlWB);
    releaseObject(xlA);
}
private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido liberar el objeto " + 
        ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```